# Why are these loop outputs different?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am working on a task where I need to sort and remove the duplicate letters in a string. I ended up with the function doing what I wanted but out of shear luck. I don't know why these lines of code produce different outputs. Could someone help me understand?

```
def format_string(string1):
    sorted1 = sorted(string1)
    print(sorted1)

    i = 0
    while i < len(sorted1) - 1:
        if sorted1[i] == sorted1[i + 1]:
            del sorted1[i + 1]
        else:
            i += 1
    return sorted1


print(format_string("aretheyhere"))
```

> ['a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'h', 'r', 'r', 't', 'y']

> ['a', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'y']

#This did what I wanted. but these seemingly similar lines don't.

```
def format_string(string1):
    sorted1 = sorted(string1)
    print(sorted1)

    i = 0
    j = i + 1
    while i < len(sorted1) - 1:
        if sorted1[i] == sorted1[j]:
            del sorted1[j]
        else:
            i += 1
    return sorted1


print(format_string("aretheyhere"))
```

> ['a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'h', 'r', 'r', 't', 'y']

> ['a', 'y']

```
def format_string(string1):
    sorted1 = sorted(string1)
    print(sorted1)

    i = 0
    while i < len(sorted1) - 1:
        if sorted1[i] == sorted1[i + 1]:
            del sorted1[i + 1]
        i += 1
    return sorted1


print(format_string("aretheyhere"))
```

> ['a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'h', 'r', 'r', 't', 'y']

> ['a', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'y']

What are the crucial differences here that change the output?

Comment: You should be using `for` loops not `while` loops in these just fyi

Comment: @Seth You can't iterate over a list you're modifying with a for loop, so this is a justifiable use of a while loop.

Comment: The problem is that you're not updating `j`.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman you can do this though: `for i, _ in enumerate(sorted1):`, which would be more Pythonic

Comment: @Seth No, you can't as the body of the loop is removing entries from `sorted1`, thus invalidating the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `j` doesn't increment because it's not updated inside your while loop, i.e. changing the value of `i` after setting the value of `j` to `i+1` does not change the value of `j`. For example, this function would give the same result as the first one because the value of `j` is updated inside the while loop:

```
def format_string(string1):
    sorted1 = sorted(string1)
    print(sorted1)

    i = 0
    while i < len(sorted1) - 1:
        j = i + 1
        if sorted1[i] == sorted1[j]:
            del sorted1[j]
        else:
            i += 1
    return sorted1


print(format_string("aretheyhere"))
```